# Cross-compile with Qt to Raspberry Pi 3B+ the addressbook (Protocol Buffer) - error symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, protocol-buffers

i'm cross-compiling from Qt (Ubuntu 19.10 - **5.12.3**) to Raspberry Pi 3B+ (**stetch**). I've success to do it, i'm able to run an app from Qt to Raspberry.

Now i want to deploy and execute an app with the .h and .cc file obtained with the protoc (protocol buffer).

So first i've installed the protocol buffer **3.10.1** in my laptop... i created the .h and .cc file then in Qt i added them in my project (**untitled.pro**).

After i've repeated the operation with this configuration:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux CC=/home/belfix/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=/home/belfix/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

In this way i've obtained the libprotobuf.a needed for the raspberry...
In Qt untitled.pro i've added this lines:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lprotobuf

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a
```

The program build and deploy but.... i've this error when i press Run

*/home/pi/untitled/bin/untitled: symbol lookup error: /home/pi/untitled/bin/untitled: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE*

**How can i fix it?**

Inside the Raspberry i tried : **ldd -d -r untitled**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ef7d000)
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76ee8000)
libprotobuf.so.21 => /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so.21 (0x76c9d000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x76770000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x762b8000)
libQt5Mqtt.so.5 => /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Mqtt.so.5 (0x76288000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x7610b000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/qt5pi/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x75ba1000)
libGLESv2.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2 (0x75b7c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x75b53000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x75a0b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x7598c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7595f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x75820000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0x757f9000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76efe000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng16.so.16 (0x757bf000)
libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x7579d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x7578a000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x75778000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x75670000)
libbrcmEGL.so => /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so (0x75637000)
libbcm_host.so => /opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so (0x7560e000)
libvchiq_arm.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvchiq_arm.so (0x755f8000)
libvcos.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvcos.so (0x755df000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x755c8000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3 (0x7554f000)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE (./untitled)
undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message25InitializationErrorStringEv (./untitled)
undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameEv   (./untitled)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal24InlineGreedyStringParserEPSsPKcPNS1_12ParseContextE (./untitled)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf2io19EpsCopyOutputStream30WriteStringMaybeAliasedOutlineEjRKSsPh   (./untitled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .pro file.

```
DEFINES += PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS
```

Actually you are linking to the dynamically built PB library. So, you need to add this preprocessor definition. You may also build PB statically if it's an option.

You may also want to note [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md):

> **Note for cross-compiling**
>
> The makefiles normally invoke the protoc executable that they just
>   built in order to build tests. When cross-compiling, the protoc
>   executable may not be executable on the host machine. In this case,
>   you must build a copy of protoc for the host machine first, then use
>   the --with-protoc option to tell configure to use it instead. For
>   example:
>
> `./configure --with-protoc=protoc`
>
> This will use the installed protoc
>   (found in your $PATH) instead of trying to execute the one built
>   during the build process. You can also use an executable that hasn't
>   been installed. For example, if you built the protobuf package for
>   your host machine in ../host, you might do:
>
> `./configure --with-protoc=../host/src/protoc`
>
> Either way, you must make
>   sure that the protoc executable you use has the same version as the
>   protobuf source code you are trying to use it with.

Comment: Thank you! I will try... the environment is Ubuntu 19.10
I tried with that "note for cross-compiling"... it doesn't work :(